# Java, runing "textArea = new JTextArea()" taking too much time

Tags: java, time, jtextarea

Something strange happened to me. For some reason, it takes a long time(1.60900 seconds) till it runs the following line:

`textArea = new JTextArea();`

I declared textArea variable as globally.
This only happens in one window (Jframe). In others it does not happen.

```
public class FAQ extends JFrame 
{
    /*--------attributes--------*/
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPaneInput;
    private JScrollPane scrollPaneQuestions;
    private JPanel paneQuestions;
    private JPanel paneSelectOrNewFAQ;
    private JButton btnEditSelection;
    private JButton btnNewFAQ;
    public JTextArea textArea;
    private JLabel lblQuestions;
    public JList list;
    private User user;
    private FAQ currentWindow;
    private int selectedFaq = 0;
    private DatabaseManager DManager;
    private Vector<FAQ_class> Faqs = new Vector<FAQ_class>();
    private JButton btnNewButton;


    /*--------methods--------*/

    public FAQ(User _user,DatabaseManager DM) 
    {
        setResizable(false);
        DManager = DM;
        addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
                Menu menu = new Menu(user,DManager);
                menu.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        currentWindow = this;
        user = _user;
        addGui();
        if(!user.rule.equals("patient"))
        {
            btnEditSelection.setEnabled(true);
            btnNewFAQ.setEnabled(true);
        }
        loadFaqs();
    }//end of FAQ
    public void loadFaqs()
    {
        Faqs = DManager.getQuestionsList();
        Vector<String> temp = new Vector<String>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < Faqs.size();i++)
        {
            temp.addElement(Faqs.get(i).question);
        }
        list.setListData(temp);

    }
    public void addGui()
    {
        setTitle("FAQ - Online medical help");
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(FAQ.class.getResource("/Images/question.png")));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 708, 438);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        addPanel();
        addPanes();
        addButtons();
        addGroupLayout();
        addJTextArea();
    }//end of addGui

    public void addPanel()
    {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.add(panel);
    }//end of addPanel

    public void addPanes()
    {
        scrollPaneInput = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPaneInput.setBounds(327, 0, 365, 398);

        paneQuestions = new JPanel();
        paneQuestions.setBounds(0, 0, 317, 38);
        paneQuestions.setBackground(new Color(154, 205, 50));
    }//end of addScrollPanes

    public void addButtons()
    {

    }//end of addButtons

    public void addJTextArea()
    {
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        scrollPaneInput.setViewportView(textArea);
    }//end of addJTextArea

    public void addGroupLayout()
    {

        lblQuestions = new JLabel("Questions");
        lblQuestions.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblQuestions.setBounds(0, 0, 317, 38);
        lblQuestions.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblQuestions.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 22));
        panel.setLayout(null);
        scrollPaneQuestions = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPaneQuestions.setBounds(0, 37, 317, 318);

                list = new JList();
                list.setSelectionBackground(new Color(154, 205, 50));
                list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
                        try
                        {

                            for(int i = 0; i<Faqs.size();i++)
                            {
                                if(!list.isSelectionEmpty())
                                    if(Faqs.get(i).question.equals(list.getSelectedValue().toString()))
                                    {
                                        textArea.setText(Faqs.get(i).answer);
                                        selectedFaq = i;
                                        break;
                                    }
                            }

                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                scrollPaneQuestions.setViewportView(list);
                panel.add(scrollPaneQuestions);
        panel.add(paneQuestions);
        paneQuestions.setLayout(null);
        paneQuestions.add(lblQuestions);
        panel.add(scrollPaneInput);

        paneSelectOrNewFAQ = new JPanel();
        paneSelectOrNewFAQ.setBounds(0, 348, 317, 50);
        btnEditSelection = new JButton("Edit Selected");
        btnEditSelection.setBounds(68, 11, 131, 40);
        btnEditSelection.setEnabled(false);
        btnEditSelection.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


            //open EditFAQ to edit FAQ
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(!list.isSelectionEmpty())
                {
                    EditFAQ faq = new EditFAQ(user,Faqs.get(selectedFaq),currentWindow,DManager);
                    faq.setVisible(true);
                    currentWindow.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You must select for the list first.");
                }
            }
        });
        btnEditSelection.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FAQ.class.getResource("/Images/tool.png")));

        btnNewFAQ = new JButton("New FAQ");
        btnNewFAQ.setBounds(203, 11, 114, 40);
        btnNewFAQ.setEnabled(false);
        btnNewFAQ.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            //open EditFAQ to make new FAQ
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                EditFAQ faq = new EditFAQ(user,null,currentWindow,DManager);
                faq.setVisible(true);
                currentWindow.setEnabled(false);
            }


        });
        btnNewFAQ.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(95, 23));
        btnNewFAQ.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(95, 23));
        btnNewFAQ.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 23));
        btnNewFAQ.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FAQ.class.getResource("/Images/add.png")));

        btnNewButton = new JButton("");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 10, 42, 41);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FAQ.class.getResource("/Images/left.png")));
        panel.add(paneSelectOrNewFAQ);
        paneSelectOrNewFAQ.setLayout(null);
        paneSelectOrNewFAQ.add(btnNewButton);
        paneSelectOrNewFAQ.add(btnEditSelection);
        paneSelectOrNewFAQ.add(btnNewFAQ);
    }//end of addGroupLayout

}//end of class
```

Comment: Until what runs it? How is it being accessed?

Comment: In what window happens?

Comment: without any further context this question will be impossible to answer.

Comment: You're probably doing some processing where you shouldn't be on a thread you shouldn't be doing it. You need to post more code.

Comment: This command stops the code until it finishes.
public JTextArea textArea; this is how i declared textArea.

in Jframe window.

there is no window threads in this class.

Comment: Canyou try comething like this?
`long start = System.currentTimeMilis();
textArea = new JTextArea();
long end = System.currentTimeMilis();
System.out.println((end-start) + " ms");`

Then tell us how much time does it takes to create that object

Comment: the result: 1609
Probably overdone it. But it still takes too much time.

Comment: Probably the problem something you do with `DatabaseManager` and `User`. What do you do before calling the contructor of FAQ? and what do you do in `Faqs = DManager.getQuestionsList();`. By the way, how do you know that the problem is related to the takes area? is this because the screen takes too much time to load? PS, try to avoid using java.util.Vector and prefer ArrayList, LinkedList, etc

Comment: user is just a class of user information.
The DatabaseManager is a class with SQL querys and connection metod. When user make login i'm creating new DB connection and 'DManager' make sure that before any SQL querys the user dont need to make new connection to the DB(saving time). before calling the contructor of FAQ i'm doing loging and select FAQ frame from the menu.
DManager.getQuestionsList(); return vector with FAQs afetr SQL query.

i know the problem is related to the text area becuse i was doing debuging before and after this line.

Answer (score 1):

*Something strange happened to me. For some reason, it takes a long time(5 second~) till it runs the following line:* 
 Run this class and give me the result:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
public class JTextAreaRunningTime {
    JTextArea textArea;
    public JTextAreaRunningTime(){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000");
String totalTime = nf.format((endTime-startTime)/1000d);
System.out.println("Execution time is " + totalTime + " seconds");
    }
    public static void main (String...argW){
        new JTextAreaRunningTime();
    }

}
```

Comment: Execution time is 1.60900 seconds

Comment: Look my edited answer, copy-past this class and run it, my result is `0.04100 seconds`.

Comment: Execution time is 0.07400 seconds

Comment: Freind can you please help me?